# What is the value of this algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If 
>   $$(x+1)+\frac1{x+1}=1$$
>   Then find
>   $$x^5+\frac1{x^5}$$

I tried hard but could not get anywhere

Comment: Hint: Do the substitution $x+1 = u$.

Comment: It seem to me, the statement have no solution in reals. I mean there is no x, for which the given equality has solution.

Comment: Hehe, are we doing the challenge of no complex numbers?

Comment: Hint: set $x + 1 = e^{i\theta}$, you get $2\cos\theta = 1$...

Comment: First equation multiply by $x+1$ and then divide by $x$ to get that $x+\frac{1}{x}=-1$ then solve by standard way

Answer (score 6):

Notice $$x+1 + \frac{1}{x+1} = 1 \iff x + \frac{1}{x+1} = 0 \implies x^2+x+1 = 0$$ 
This implies
$$x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1) = 0$$

As a result,
$$x^5 + \frac{1}{x^5} = (x^3)(x^2) + \frac{x}{(x^3)^2} = x^2 + x = -1$$

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging gives:

$(x+1)^2+1=x+1$

$x^2+2x+1+1=x+1$

$x^2+1=-x$

$x+\frac{1}{x}=-1$

Cubing gives:

$x^3+3x+\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^3}=-1\implies x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=-1-3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=2$

Raising it to the 5th power gives:

$x^5+5x^3+10x+\frac{10}{x}+\frac{5}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^5}=-1\implies x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}=-1-5\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)-10\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=-1$

Comment: `\implies` instead of `\to` or `\rightarrow` will render as $\implies$ instead of $\to$.  Just personal preference.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yeh that does look better. Thanks.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks again. Was about to fix those but you beat me to it.

Comment: Lol, no problemo.